# How does node expansion work in neo4j browser?

Tags: neo4j

When I expand (double-click) a node in the neo4j browser, it expands to show all its neighbors. Does it call a query to do that or is some other mechanism used? I ask because I want to replicate this behavior in a web application to render a neo4j graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The neo4j Browser does a query when you double-click on an un-"expanded" node.

The double-click event handler code is [here](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-browser/blob/6a30bfc29add7e02030d4b1bebcda3f0ed3344b7/src/browser/modules/D3Visualization/GraphEventHandler.js#L101), which eventually calls [this code](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-browser/blob/65e43abf5e65615e650a3921a9c021009e21177a/src/browser/modules/Stream/CypherFrame/VisualizationView.jsx#L105) to make the query.

Comment: Can I change this `getNeighbours` function's query? I only need one direction relation `MATCH path = (a)-->(o)`

Comment: @PaleNeutron It is technically feasible for you to fork the necessary github repos to make such a tweak. But, practically speaking, I doubt it will be worth all the effort.